# Why is there an extra row in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to bind a grid to the following data source. Why do i get an extra row in there  when there is not data in it? The count of the rows is also correct , i can see that when i debug .

[image: Grid snapshot]

```
 Object[] users = new Object[100];
                        int i = 0;
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                              users[i++] =  new  {
                                                userid= reader.GetString(0),
                                                group = reader.GetString(1),
                                                subgroup = reader.GetString(2),
                                              };
                        }
                        gridview_UserAccess.DataSource = users;
                        gridview_UserAccess.DataBind();

<asp:GridView ID="gridview_UserAccess" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
   <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">                   
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbox_Select" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>    
</Columns>

        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />            
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />

  </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have a blank Line in your file. Because of this reader.Read() is true. Userid, group and subgroup are empty strings. So an User Object is created with empty values leading it to the empty row.

Comment: good thought , but i found the solution..not the root cause though. The moment i fixed the size of the array to exactly the row count i was receiving , there were no extra rows. Why needs more thought i guess..

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because your are incrementing i on the first read thus leaving users[0] blank? Try to change your code to the following:

```
int i = -1;
while (reader.Read())
{
    users[i++] =  new  {
    userid= reader.GetString(0),
    group = reader.GetString(1),
    subgroup = reader.GetString(2),
    };
}
```

Comment: unless I'm missing something, that's not the way the post ++ operator works. i++ will be evaluated as -1 on the first iteration of your code, which will probably throw an indexoutofrange exception.

Comment: i++ increments after it's called, ++i would increment before

Comment: that does not seem to be the case , my users are there from index 0 to 4 i.e. 5 users

Comment: i++ returns i , so this code will generate IndexOutOfRange error.